# jquery popup on second visit

Tags: jquery, cookies, popup

I'm trying to get a popup to appear on the users second visit to the page, I'm sure it can be done using cookies I just have no idea how to do it.

I'm using the Zurb Reveal Modal. At the moment it pops up on page load and then won't pop up again until after 2 days.

Instead I would like it to pop up initially on their second visit to the site, doesn't matter if its within the same day. Is this possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
if (jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1') { 
jQuery('#myModal').reveal() 
jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click'); 
jQuery.cookie('sale', '1', { expires: 2}); } 
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var tmrReveal = null;    
$('a[#myModal]').live('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var modalLocation = $(this).attr('#myModal');
if (tmrReveal != null)
clearTimeout(tmrReveal);
tmrReveal = setTimeout(
function() {
$('#'+modalLocation).reveal($(this).data()); 
},10000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: If the user comes back twice within 2 days, then comes back twice within 2 days in the following month, would they get the popup on both occasions?

Comment: Sorry I think it was a bit confusing what I wrote, i've updated it to be a bit simpler

Comment: My question is more: "if the user gets the popup after their 2nd visit, would they never ever get it again?"

Comment: it would be useful if they didn't get it for the following 2 weeks rather than never get it again, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is the following:

When a user visits and the cookie is not set then set it to `1` as you have now but don't show anything. The cookie at this point will expire in 2 days.

If the user re-visits within 2 days and the cookie is set as `1` then show the popup and set the cookie to '2' and have it expire after 14 days.

If the cookie is set but it's not `1` then don't do anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        if (jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1' && jQuery.cookie('sale') != '2') {
            jQuery.cookie('sale', '1', {expires: 2}); 
        } else if (jQuery.cookie('sale') == 1) {
            jQuery('#myModal').reveal();
            jQuery('#myModal').trigger('click');
            jQuery.cookie('sale', '2', {expires: 14}); 
        }
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var tmrReveal = null;
    $('a[#myModal]').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var modalLocation = $(this).attr('#myModal');
        if (tmrReveal != null)
            clearTimeout(tmrReveal);
        tmrReveal = setTimeout(
                function () {
                    $('#' + modalLocation).reveal($(this).data());
                }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

I have not tested this but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, that didn't work but I changed the 3rd line to 
        if (jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1') { 
            jQuery.cookie('sale', '1', {expires: 2}); 
      and that seemed to work, at least it popped up on the second visit, can you see any problems with doing that?

Comment: @jimmy345 no that should still work. I wasn't sure how jQuery cookie checks if a cookie is set or not. I'll update the answer. The idea is to check if the cookie is already set (which is why I'm doing `jQuery.cookie('sale') != '1' && jQuery.cookie('sale') != '2'` in the updated answer).

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much, works perfectly. I've +1 but it won't show until i've got a rep of 15...